# How can i pick data from a data frame dynamically?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to pick data from the 6th row of the data frame but the columns vary in number.

What i already have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df_csv)
```

```
     val0 = df.iloc[6:, 0]
     val1 = df.iloc[6:, 1]
     val2 = df.iloc[6:, 2]
     val3 = df.iloc[6:, 3]
     val4 = df.iloc[6:, 4]
```

What I want is it should even store dynamically.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(df_csv)
 for i in df:
    val[i] = df.iloc[6:, i]
```

Comment: save them into dict

Comment: So it would be `list(df_count.iloc[6,:])` or `dict(df_count.iloc[6,:])` (what @WeNYoBen probably meant).

Comment: 6th row or 6th row onwards?

Comment: @anky_91 6th row onwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be as already mentioned:

```
df = df_csv[6:]
simple_dict = dict(df)
```

This stores each column as a pandas.Series in the dict.
However as pandas.Series are storing non-existing values as `NaN` let's drop these:

```
storage = {}
for column_name, column_values in df.iteritems():
    series = column_values.dropna()
    storage[column_name] = series
```

#### Check memory consumption:

As the python interpreter only references objects to the dict, we have to sum up the size of all referenced objects:

```
memory_size = storage.__sizeof__()
for key in storage:
    memory_size += storage[key].__sizeof__()
```

The output from the `__sizeof__()` method is not always trustworthy, so another way to check this is to serialize the objects with the `pickle` module. In this case this seems to match quite good.

> Now you can compare`memory_size` of both dicts: `storage` and `simple_dict`. In my tests with float64, the density of the `DataFrame` has to be <50% to have an advantage of dropping the `NaN`, above >50% it is even an disadvantage both in terms of memory and computation time.